# FK for composite key splitted into 2 when table with certain name is added

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, dbeaver, ef-core-6.0

So I have the following entities defined.

```cs
internal class DeliveryArea
{
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DeliveryPrice> HasDeliveryPrices { get; set; }
}

internal class DeliveryPrice
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }

    public DeliveryArea ForDeliveryArea { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAreaPostcode { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAreaState { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAreaCountry { get; set; }
}
```

and my `DbContext` is as follow

```cs
internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // DbSets.
    public DbSet<DeliveryArea> DeliveryAreas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeliveryPrice> DeliveryPrices { get; set; }

    // Overrides.
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=Test.EFCore.db;");
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        #region DeliveryArea.
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryArea>();

            // Setup case-insensitive columns.
            entity.Property(i => i.Postcode).HasColumnType("TEXT COLLATE NOCASE");
            entity.Property(i => i.State).HasColumnType("TEXT COLLATE NOCASE");
            entity.Property(i => i.Country).HasColumnType("TEXT COLLATE NOCASE");
            // Setup composite PK.
            entity.HasKey(nameof(DeliveryArea.Postcode), nameof(DeliveryArea.State), nameof(DeliveryArea.Country));
        }
        #endregion

        #region DeliveryPrice.
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryPrice>();

            // DeliveryPrice x DeliveryArea | many-to-one
            entity.HasOne(left => left.ForDeliveryArea)
                .WithMany(right => right.HasDeliveryPrices)
                .HasForeignKey(left => new { left.DeliveryAreaPostcode, left.DeliveryAreaState, left.DeliveryAreaCountry });
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

When the database is generated, EF Core manage to generate appropriate FK that connects both table using the composite key. Everything looks fine and the diagram looks great.

[image: Good diagram]

Now, I added the following entity

```cs
internal class Currency
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DeliveryPrice> ForDeliveryPrices { get; set; }
}
```

and updated `DeliveryPrice` class as follow

```cs
internal class DeliveryPrice
{
    public uint Id { get; set; }

    // Add the following
    public Currency HasCurrency { get; set; }
    public uint HasCurrencyId { get; set; }

    public DeliveryArea ForDeliveryArea { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAreaPostcode { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAreaState { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryAreaCountry { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext` is updated on top of existing, as follow

```cs
internal class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    // DbSets.
    public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }

    // Existing codes remain...

    // Overrides.
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        #region Currency.
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>();
            // Currency x DeliveryPrice | one-to-many
            entity.HasMany(left => left.ForDeliveryPrices)
                .WithOne(right => right.HasCurrency)
                .HasForeignKey(right => right.HasCurrencyId);
        }
        #endregion
        
        // Existing codes remain...
    }
}
```

When the new database is generated, the FK that connects both `DeliveryArea` and `DeliveryPrice` table is kinda splitted into 2, as follow

[image: FK splitted]

The funny thing is that when the `Currencies` table is renamed to, say `Foo`, the FK that connects both `DeliveryArea` and `DeliveryPrice` table looks OK.

[image: Now the FK looks OK]

UPDATE 01:

Normal looking FK

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the generated FK that splitted into 2

[image]

UPDATE 02:

Upon looking further into the issue, I've found that this is specific to DBeaver only. Viewing the same database file with other database viewer (e.g. DbSchema) does not have the issue.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Hmm, are you sure this is not just visual diagram rendering issue? Have you checked the actual FK in the database?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm using DBeaver to render the diagram. From DBeaver, I can see that there're 2 FK generated: `FK_DeliveryPrices_DeliveryAreas` and `FK_DeliveryPrices_DeliveryAreas_2`. I'm pretty sure it is not the rendering issue.

Comment: @IvanStoev you could be right. I've found that viewing the same database file with other database viewer generates only one FK and therefore does not have the issue.